# Grant truncate permissions on all tables with out modify

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Is there a way I can grant truncate permission to a user without altering privileges in SQL Server?

Comment: Truncate is a DDL operation so no.

Comment: I think the [fine manual covers this pretty extensively](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions): "The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles, and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo  
WITH EXECUTE AS 'CompanyDomain\SqlUser1'  
AS  
SELECT user_name();
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can go through this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I suggest [signing the proc](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) rather than `EXECUTE AS`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test Login and User id then grant it execute permission on the stored procedure Truncate_Table_Loner. This id will be used to perform the truncate.

```
-- Grant Execute Permission
-- Setup ID on Database with Connect permission
USE master 
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test_user_id] WITH PASSWORD = 'JustConnect123';
GO
USE TestSQL
GO
CREATE USER [test_user_id] FOR LOGIN [test_user_id];
GO
-- Grant Permission
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.Truncate_Table_Loner TO [test_user_id];
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I don't think it will work as `TRUNCATE` doesn't honor ownership chaining.

Comment: This answer only provided Step 3 and missed Step 1/2 (create proxy user and proc). 
Source is here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2583/grant-truncate-table-permissions-in-sql-server-without-alter-table/